# Google App Engine Query Not Working in Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

Riddle me this Stackoverflow:

I have a query that I am sending to GAE. The query (When in String format) looks like this:
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE USER_ID = 5884677008

If I go to the GAE console and type it in via a manual GQL query, it returns the item just fine. If I browse via the GUI and scroll to it, I can see it just fine. But when I call it from the Java code, it returns nothing every time. 
code:

I have already confirmed the query is correct as I printed it out as a String just so I can test it.

Anyone have any idea what is going on with this?

```
    q = new Query(entityName); //entityName = "User", confirmed
    q.setFilter(filter); //filter = "USER_ID = 5884677008", confirmed
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
    /*
    This always is empty here. Calling either pq.countEntities()); or
    pq.toString()); returns size 0 or a String of nothing.
    */
```

Thanks!
-Sil

Edit: I Do have an index built, but it did not seem to help with the problem.

Comment: `countEntities()` is [deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/PreparedQuery). What does `asSingleEntity()` give you?

Comment: It is indeed deprecated, it still worked, but should probably be mentioned (as you did) that it is deprecated in case it gets removed entirely in the future.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32980349/google-app-engine-query-not-working-in-java), you don't necessarily need to do toString. Have you tried asIterable or asSingleEntity on pq? Something like:

```
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);

for (Entity result : pq.asIterable()) {
  String test = (String) result.getProperty("prop1");
}
```

That's if you have multiple entries. In the event you only have one:

```
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);

Entity result = pq.asSingleEntity();
String test = (String) result.getProperty("prop1");
```

Basically, if you don't call asIterable or asSingleEntity, the query is JUST prepared and doesn't run

Comment: Although this didn't help me with my specific problem, you bring up an excellent point, to actually utilize the entities stored in the pq, you do need to call a method against it and then iterate through the results. I posted the solution above; turns out it was a casting issue.

Answer (score 2):

Took quite a bit of testing, but found the issue.

The problem revolved around the filter being set. If I removed the filter, it worked fine (but returned everything). Turns out, what was being passed as a filter was a String version of the user_id as opposed to the Long version of it. There was really no way to tell as the exact SQL query DID NOT read ( SELECT * FROM USER WHERE USER_ID = "5884677008" ) when I printed it, which would have been a dead giveaway.

I changed the passed filter parameter (which I had stored in a hashmap of (String, Object) btw) from a String to a Long and that solved the issue.

One thing to point out though, as @Patrice brought up (And as I excluded from my code while posting to save space), to actually iterate through the list of results, you do need to call a method against it (Either .asIterable() or .asSingleEntity() ).

You actually can check against the number of returned entities / results by calling pq.countEntities() and it will return the correct number even before you call a formatting method against the pq, but as @tx802 pointed out, it is deprecated, and despite the fact that it worked for me, someone in the future using this post as a reference may not have it work for them.